# File and line numbers in F# code quotations

Tags: f#

Is there a way to extract the file name and line number from code quotation so that we may add add debug information for transformations of the quoted code. Any alternative ways?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
let sourceInfo (e:Quotations.Expr) = 
    let (|Val|_|) e : 't option = 
        match e with
        | Quotations.Patterns.Value(:? 't as v,_) -> Some v
        | _ -> None
    let (|Tup|_|) = Quotations.Patterns.(|NewTuple|_|)

    e.CustomAttributes
    |> List.tryPick (function | Tup [Val("DebugRange")
                                     Tup [Val(file:string)
                                          Val(startLine:int) 
                                          Val(startCol:int)
                                          Val(endLine:int)
                                          Val(endCol:int)]] 
                                  -> Some(file,startLine,startCol,endLine,endCol) 
                              | _ -> None)

sourceInfo <@ "test" @>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now built into F#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233234.aspx

```
__LINE__
__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
__SOURCE_FILE__
```